# Make INSERT query go slower or check if value exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one encrypted scalar-valued function that is based on the current time to generate unique ids for a table. Let's call the function **dbo.GenerateRecID**

I have an INSERT query in SQL Server which then calls this function to insert the unique Record ID for a table.

Let this table be called **Contacts** which has the following columns:

```
RecID varchar(15)
Name varchar(20)
Age varchar(50)
```

I want to insert **Contacts** from another table called **Users** like this

```
INSERT INTO Contacts (RecID,Name,Age) values (SELECT dbo.GenerateRecID(),UserName,UserAge FROM USERS)
```

The issue with this is that the INSERT with the function **dbo.GenerateRecID()** (which is an encrypted function that the software supplies for us so I can't change it) is too fast. Since it gets called multiple times per millisecond, it generates the same ID, so I'm getting duplicated values when inserting.

Is there a way to create a delay for each inserted row to make the function generate multiple ID's and avoid this issue (just like a for each and a sleep in programming)? Or as an alternative, is there a way to use try and catch to check if a duplicate is being inserted and call again that function?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239879/discussion-on-question-by-pedro-emilio-velez-make-insert-query-go-slower-or-chec).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a per User insert and making sure the RecID does not exists in the Contacts database

```
declare @newID varchar(15)

while exists(select 1 from USERS where not exists (select 1 from contacts where name = username))  -- get Users which are not in the Contacts table
begin
       select @newID =  dbo.GenerateRecID()  -- gets the new ID
  
       while not exists(select 1 from contacts where RecID = @newID)   -- if newID is not in Contacts then use it otherwise generate a new one
         begin
             insert into Contacts(RecID,Name,Age)   -- Insert users 1 at a time
             select top 1 @newID,UserName,UserAge from USERS
             where not exists (select 1 from contacts where name = username))

         end

end
```